Google Sheets Script ERROR: RANGE NOT FOUND for line: sheet.getRange('E${lastRow}').setValue(value)
I was following a video for Google Sheets to create a live portfolio growth tracker for stock trading. Here is a link to the video. The script is about 3 years old and there seems to be a problem. The error happens on the same line for both sheets of script.
sheet.getRange('E${lastRow}').setValue(value)
sheet.getRange('H${lastRow}').setValue(value)
Any ideas how I can fix it?
DayChart.gs:
function dailyChart() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PvD (Auto)");
  var value = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var range = sheet.getRange("E1:E").getValues();
  var lastRow = null;
  var i = 0;
  while(i < range.length) {
    if (range[i][0] !==""){
      i++;
    } else {
      lastRow = i +1;
      break;
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange('E${lastRow}').setValue(value)
}

LifetimeChart.gs:
function dayChartDelete() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PvD (Auto)");
  var range = sheet.getRange("E2:E");
  range.clear();
}

function lifeTimeChart() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PvD (Auto)");
  var value = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var range = sheet.getRange("H1:H").getValues();
  var lastRow = null;
  var i = 0;
  while(i < range.length) {
   if (range[i][0] !== "") {
      i++;
    } else {
      lastRow = i + 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange('H${lastRow}').setValue(value)
}

I have 2 sheets. 1 with an updating net value and dropdown with 2 options, Lifetime and 1 Day. The other page, PvD (Auto) is supposed to be where the constantly updating values are plugged into so that they can be used to create a visual reference chart. There are also 3 triggers (as per vid instructions). Cannot get the script to work and begin live-generating numbers. If I remove the line of code the error disappears but nothing happens.

If you have solved the problem You might post the solution as an answer, or, as the question hasn't an answer yet, delete it. Questions should not have meta commentaries like "Fixed"

For those, like me, who were mystified by this getRange() method, the script uses Template literals which were introduced with the V8 Runtime but has been available in Javascript for some time.

The getRange() method in both "DayChart.gs" and "LifetimeChart.gs" uses Template literals (AKA "Template strings" and "string literals").

Template literals are literals delimited with backtick (`) characters

When setting the range, the OP script uses single quotes:

sheet.getRange('E${lastRow}').setValue(value)

However, the script in the video (and this is stressed at 15:48) uses backticks (the character under the tilde).

sheet.getRange(`E${lastRow}`).setValue(value)


